# Download an active Storage attachment to disc

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

[The guide](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#downloading-files) says that I can save an attachment to disc to run a process on it like this:

```
message.video.open do |file|
  system '/path/to/virus/scanner', file.path
  # ...
end
```

My model has an attachment defined as:

```
has_one_attached :zip
```

And then in the model I have defined:

```
def process_zip      
  zip.open do |file|
    # process the zip file
  end
end
```

However I am getting an error :

```
private method `open' called
```

on the zip.open call.

How can I save the zip locally for processing?

Answer (score 12):

As an alternative in Rails 5.2 you can do this:

```
def process_zip      
   # Download the zip file in temp dir
   zip_path = "#{Dir.tmpdir}/#{zip.filename}"
   File.open(zip_path, 'wb') do |file|
       file.write(zip.download)
   end   

   Zip::File.open(zip_path) do |zip_file|  
       # process the zip file
       # ...
       puts "processing file #{zip_file}"
   end
end
```

Comment: Maybe it's better to use `Rails.root.join('tmp').to_s` instead of `Dir.tmpdir`?

Comment: I prefer `Tempfile.open { |tempfile| tempfile << zip.download }.path` to get the path of a tempfile with the contents of `zip`

Comment: I think chosing a better directory is a kind of taste, meanwhile the recipe generally works awesome!

Answer (score 1):

That’s an edge guide (note `edgeguides.rubyonrails.org` in the URL); it applies to the master branch of the [rails/rails](https://github.com/rails/rails) repository on GitHub. The latest changes in master haven’t been included in a released version of Rails yet.

You’re likely using Rails 5.2. Use edge Rails to take advantage of `ActiveStorage::Blob#open`:

```
gem "rails", github: "rails/rails"
```