# How to download ActiveStorage attachments to tmpdir

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

The objective is to download an attached file to tempdir for subsequent usage. [The documentation](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#downloading-files) says to use `ActiveStorage::Blob#open` which seems simple enough.

**I'm getting errors so please explain what I'm doing wrong:**

1. Calling `@flower.photo.open` results in `NoMethodError (private method 'open' called for #<ActiveStorage::Attached::One:0x00007f9780625100>)`
2. Calling @flower.photo.blob.open` results in `NoMethodError (private method 'open' called for #<ActiveStorage::Blob:0x00007f9780615c50>)`

Examining [the source code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activestorage/app/models/active_storage/blob.rb#L169) I'm not sure why I'm getting the private method error.

Comment: "private method 'open'" errors usually mean you're accidentally picking up [`Kernel#open`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-open), that shouldn't be happening with `ActiveStorage::Blob` though. How is `@flower.photo` defined?

Comment: How is it defined? Well, @flower.photo is successfully attached using standard ActiveStorage methods. I know this because `@flower.photo.attached?` returns `true` and I can successfully display the photo in the view.

Comment: But what does it look like in the `Flower` model?

Comment: It looks like it should in the model: `has_one_attached :photo` though I posted the answer below. I wasn't doing anything wrong... other than not using edge rails. ;-)

Answer (score 5):

That method isn't released until rails 6 next year.

There’s a [similar SO question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50529659/download-an-active-storage-attachment-to-disc) with more info and a recommendation.